# Change the src of video tag or iframe to my domain name / id in PHP Youtube clone Script

Tags: php, video, clone, youtube-data-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am working on a php youtube clone script, similar to `playit.pk`

If you have experience with such a script then you could probably help me.

On th page watch.php where an iframe is used to view youtube video in the iframe the php source code is:

```
src="//www.v.ytapi.com/embed/<?php echo $yt->id ?>
```

but I want to replace it with

```
src="//www.myDomainName.com/embed/<?php echo $yt->id ?>
```

How can I achieve that or else Instead of iframe how can I get src like this

```
http://r5---sn-vgqs7n7y.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback
```

and directly use it in a video tag.

Comment: `only then you can help me...!` okay... guess I can't help you. I have no idea what that is but I do know how to change text.

Comment: chris85 if you may tell me how can i get src in my video tag by using youtube video id? Did you visited site playit.pk i want to source my video tag like them!

Comment: So, you want direct access to the youtube video file? Sure, poke around on the API. Probably there's something. You can try to use `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/<video id>` to get some info.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel good but problem I am facing is that youtube is blocked in pakistan so either i directly get it through google's server or use some proxy server and view my domain name

Comment: I honestly don't know if there is an alternative for an youtube video. But you can poke around on `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/6_b7RDuLwcI` (use TOR to get the content) and see if you can access the video using VLC. Look for `media:content` and you will have a list of all the URLs. You can try to look for the alternatives and see if an url pointing to `google.com` will work instead of `youtube.com`. On that example, one of the URLs is `rtsp://r6---sn-cg07luez.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQnCwYs7RPv26xMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp`. This won't work for every video.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel if you visit this link: http://www.v.ytapi.com/embed/VRlmCf1Kj2o , and inspect src of video. This is 3rd party site accessing youtube video, so like this if i can access youtube video I can enable user to embed video with my domain like-> http://www.example.com/embed/video_id...  check it..!

Comment: @user3027447 "`Can NOT download video!`" :/